# Go to specific page using Django Pagination with restframework

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a question about going to specific page using pagination in Django restframework.
(Data needs to be rendered to HTML)

Example:

model.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
class BookListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    template_name = 'booklist.html'
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    pagination_class = BookPagination
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = ProtocolSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(serializer.data)
        return self.get_paginated_response(page)
```

I can show the paginated item with the codes above.
And there are next and previous links in HTML.
However, I need page list like [1,2,3,....], not just next and previous.
I can view the data on the 3rd page by just click button 3.
I need some steps to do this.

1: Retrieve the target page number(I don't know how to do this)

2: Get the data of on that page

3: Render to HTML

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Out of scope question: you are using rest_framework to render html?

Comment: I think you need to use filter with pagination <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904087/django-rest-framework-pagination-and-filtering>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own paginator by subclassing `PageNumberPagination` to add a list of all available pages to the response:

```
class AllPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('pages', self.get_all_pages_links()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))

    def get_all_pages_links(self):
       base_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        
       def page_number_to_url(page_number):
            if page_number == 1:
                return remove_query_param(base_url, self.page_query_param)
            else:
                return replace_query_param(base_url, self.page_query_param, page_number)
       
       page_numbers = range(1, self.page.paginator.num_pages + 1)

       page_links = []
       for page_number in page_numbers:
           page_links.append(page_number_to_url(page_number))

       return page_links
```